# How do I disable UL style?

Tags: html, css

I am using css Style to do a drop down menu.  The menu uses UL / LI html tags.  I also use UL/LI combination later on display text.

Using https://www.webydo.com/blog/web-design/freebies/25-winning-navigation-menus-to-download/  (number 7)

The menu works and I get the drop down how I like.  The problem is that bulletpoints in the bellow document use the menu format.  How do I override the UL/LI format so I get bulletpoints.  I presume I could do

```
<ul class="x">
```

where x is the name of the css class but I don't know what css style would be.  Would I also need to apply a css class to the enclosed li tags?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you want bullet points? Or remove them.

Comment: Bulletpoints please.

Answer (score 0):

You can change them with CSS `list-style-type`

Made an example, as you can see, bullet points are default

You can also change them to bullets, with `list-style-type: disc;` or `list-style-type: circle;` where they have a space in the middle

```css
.custom {
  list-style-type: square;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>1</li>
  <li>2</li>
  <li>3</li>
  <li>4</li>
</ul>

<ul class="custom">
  <li>1</li>
  <li>2</li>
  <li>3</li>
  <li>4</li>
</ul>
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bxk5qe1c/1/)

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing the full code and only the example you've provided in the link. To apply bullet points to a `<ul>` list, add the following **CSS** to your `x` class.

```
x {
    list-style-type: circle;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

On your list item elements `<li>` you are going to set the `list-style-type` to a value of `initial`.

Alternatively, there are other options available if you want, like squares or hollow circles, etc. But you should only use these ones if you want to force a particular style. `Initial` will default to the browser/OS default style.

Answer (score 0):

You can override the UL style by inserting a class that has got a different style type in the UL. for example

the CSS

```
ul.custom{
    list-style-type: square;
    }
```

the HTML

```
<ul>
   <li>First</li>
   <li>Second</li>
   <li>Third</li>
   <li>Etc</li>
</ul>
```